# How to update Qt from 5.5.1 to 5.9.5 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, updates, 18.04, qt

Currently, Ubuntu 16.04 has Qt up to 5.5.1 while Ubuntu 18.04 has Qt up to 5.9.5. Currently I'm forced to use Ubuntu 16.04, however, I need to use a program that needs Qt 5.9. How could I update Qt to version 5.9.5?

---

Note that I'm configuring it on a docker container. This means that the solution shouldn't involve GUI.

Comment: You need to either find a ppa or co.pile it yourself. Get a start and post back if you have problems

Comment: @Panther I know that the command to add a ppa is something like `add-apt-repository ppa:<ppa_name>` and the  I need is [this](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/qt5-default). However, I don't know the ppa name nor how to search for it.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=ppa.qt5&oq=ppa.qt5

Comment: @Panther Seriously, I appreciate when someone tries to make me understand a bit instead of giving to me a copy-paste solution. However, even with your link, I don't understand which is the name of Ubuntu 18 repository that has the version I need.

Comment: @Panther On anther system, with 18.04 I installed them at first try with `apt-get`. The problem is that on 16.04 I don't have the same packages.

Comment: @Panther I'm forced to do it on 16.04. I tried on my system, that has 18.04 and works fine. As I said, I don't know how to add the right ppa, I don't know the name and I don't know where to search for it.

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/build-sources.html and post back if you have a problem

Comment: I need this solution as well. Was anybody able to verify that they would be able to get Qt updated to 5.9 or greater on 16.04 via command line? I'm at the moment downloading a 16.04.5 iso but I have another 12 hours before it completes and I can test it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A second option is to add Qt using a PPA. The example below installs Qt 5.11.1. There are PPA's for other versions if required.

**Add the PPA**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:beineri/opt-qt-5.11.1-xenial
sudo apt update
```

**Install Qt**

```
sudo apt install qt511-meta-full
```

**Configure the System**

There are a couple of choices here depending on whether you want to configure the use of the new Qt version system wide or to the current user.

For system wide, create the following file in location `/etc/xdg/qtchooser`.

For the current user, create the following file in location `~/.config/qtchooser`.

Create a text file in the chosen qtchooser folder named `default.conf` with the following contents:

```
/opt/qt511/bin
/opt/qt511/lib
```

The first line in the file is the path to the Qt binaries and the second is the path to the Qt libraries.

**Check the Configuration**

```
qmake -v
```

If the configuration is working correctly you should see something like:

```
QMake version 3.1
Using Qt version 5.11.1 in /opt/qt511/lib
```

Comment: @roger no, that’s not correct. That would install the packaged version from the Ubuntu repositories which is not what the user that asked this question wanted.

Comment: Thank you -- I've deleted my comment. I was trying to compile current Konsole on Ubuntu 16.04 and that command looked like it helped for a while. I gave up, eventually.

Answer (score 6):

You could install Qt using the installers provided by Qt. The open source installer can be downloaded [here](https://www.qt.io/download).

Once downloaded (the following assumes the download location is ~/Downloads):

**Install Qt**

```
cd ~/Downloads
chmod +x qt-unified-linux-x64-3.0.5-online.run
./qt-unified-linux-x64-3.0.5-online.run
```

In the "Installation Folder" screen, enter `/opt/Qt`.

[image: Qt Install Folder]

In the "Select Components" screen, choose the version you would like to install (Qt 5.11.1 used in this example) and tick the "Desktop gcc 64-bit" option.

[image: Qt Select Components]

The installer will request your sudo password during installation.

**Configure the System**

There are a couple of choices here depending on whether you want to configure the use of the new Qt version system wide or to the current user.

For system wide, create the folder `qtchooser` in location `/etc/xdg/` (the location used in this example).

For the current user, create the folder `qtchooser` in location `~/.config/`.

Create a text file in the `qtchooser` folder created in the previous step named `default.conf` with the following contents:

```
/opt/Qt/5.11.1/gcc_64/bin
/opt/Qt/5.11.1/gcc_64/lib
```

The first line in the file is the path to the Qt binaries and the second is the path to the Qt libraries.

**Check the Configuration**

```
qmake -v
```

If the configuration is working correctly you should see something like:

```
QMake version 3.1
Using Qt version 5.11.1 in /opt/Qt/5.11.1/gcc_64/lib
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention one important thing: I'm configuring it on a docker container. This means that the solution shouldn't involve GUI.

Comment: Ok. I've added another answer using a PPA.