# Change (ubuntu/kdeneon) system QT PATH

Tags: application-development, qt

im crazy trying to changing the system qt path.

because i install qtcreator and all developer libs with the qtcreator install from official site in /opt/Qt.

the problem is that the system is using the default ubuntu qt ubication, so for example if i work with qtcreator not problem but if work with kdevelop its using the system qt headers and no found a lot of things, al whant to make  kdevelop and system use /opt/Qt

i already try changing the default.conf of qtchooser but not work.

who i can make my kde neon distro use my /opt/Qt libs and headers

thanks!

Comment: As for me this is very bad idea. Why do you not want to install Qt development stuff from official repository? What is an advantage of using binary Qt in /opt?

Comment: Take a look at the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1062046/how-to-update-qt-from-5-5-1-to-5-9-5-on-ubuntu-16-04/1062323#1062323) that is based on installation of Qt using the installer. As you've already installed Qt, you can skip to the "Configure the System" section.